# Facebook Requests Dialog appears behind DIV (in Safari)

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, apprequests

I have several DIVs with z-indexes (like: z-index: 999991;). In Safari, this results that the Requests Dialog I have created appears behind some DIV's.

Is their a way to give the Requests Dialog a z-index or something so it will always appear on top of every DIV?

My Requests Dialog code:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    <p>
    <input type="button"
      onclick="sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector(); return false;"
      value="Send Request to Many Users with MFS"
    />
    </p>

    <script>
      function sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector() {
        FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
          message: 'Join me on Mahjong Solitaire!',
          exclude_ids: '<?php echo $friends_array; ?>'
        }, requestCallback);
      }

      function requestCallback(response) {
        // Handle callback here
      }
    </script>
```

Hope this is possible!

Comment: Why do you have z-indexes that are so high?

Comment: It's a beta page so I use huge nrs (makes it easier to edit the z-index if you need to squeez a new DIV in)

Comment: If you play with z-indexes that high you'll probably always be above things.  It would be a mistake to do so.  In the final version of the page i'm sure once you have returned the z-indexes to their normal range that things will work fine in all browsers.

Comment: Made the z-index smaller and this indeed worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made the z-index smaller and this indeed worked!